# Curl giving different responses on connection timeout

Tags: networking, curl

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and I try to `curl` the unavailable resource like:

`curl 192.168.11.1 --connect-timeout 10`

`curl 192.168.11.1 --connect-timeout 35`

Why does it sometimes respond with
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.11.1 port 80: No route to host`, and sometimes with `curl: (28) Connection timed out after 35001 milliseconds`, even on the same timeout?

EDIT: I now tried making HTTP request with `nodeJS`'s http request library from the same Ubuntu client. And sometimes I get `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.9.1:80` and other times I get `Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 192.168.9.1:80`.

Comment: check port 80 port is running or not using below command. if it's running then check filewall(iptables) it is open or not. also, check route is available for provided host. If it is the same server then try with curl http://localhost also .
sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 80

Comment: You want me to check that on the server or on the client? I did on the client and I got no results from this command. This server does not exist at the moment, so it is unavailable. I'm asking about the error messages I'm getting in response.

Comment: `--verbose` or `--trace` should provide some more info on what `curl` is doing behind the scenes. I wonder if it's a bad firewall configuration on the server.